# OnLongClick stopping OnClick

Tags: java, android, list, adapter, onclicklistener

I am using a Listview. before implementing OnLongClick, my onListItemClick was working perfectly, however now, after implementing OnLongClick the long clicks work and normal list clicks don't do anything. It seems to hide exposure to the onListItemClick() function you already have working

can anyone see why/ suggest a solution?

```
public class CombChange extends ListActivity {
    @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setListAdapter(new ListEdit(this, symbols));

@Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

  String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
  if (lastPressed.equals(selectedValue) ){
   count++;}
}

public class ListEdit extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnLongClickListener{
 private final Context context;
 private final String[] values;

 public ListEdit(Context context, String[] values) {
  super(context, R.layout.activity_comb_change, values);
  this.context = context;
  this.values = values;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_comb_change, parent, false);
  TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
  textView.setText(values[position]);
  rowView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){

            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
             context.startActivity(new Intent(context,RestoreOriginal.class));
                return false;
            }
        });
 // Change icon based on name
  String s = values[position];

  if (s.equals("a")) {
   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);

return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting onLongClickListener on row view instead of on ListView itself?

Comment: You need to assign listeners to ListView not to each row.

Comment: @Marek Sebera I was following someones advice as I couldn't find where to set OnLongClickListener. Would you be able to offer a suggestion?

Comment: standard, `ListView.setOnLongClickListener(listener)`

Comment: @Marek Sebera I don't use a listview, how can i access it?

Comment: @user2233667 you do use ListView, see EntryLevelDev answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I think you shouldn't do ***rowView.setOnLongClickListener***.

Try something likes this:

```
this.getListView().setLongClickable(true);
this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
// whatever you wanna do
        return true;
    }
});
```

I took the code from [how to capture long press event for Listeview item of a ListActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141882/how-to-capture-long-press-event-for-listeview-item-of-a-listactivity)

Hope this helps.