# OnClick listerner seems to stop OnLongClick?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview in which previously every item was clickable, and it worked fine. But as soon as I added a feature to have all items long clicked, the onClick feature stopped working. I stripped down all my code for debugging purposes which I will submit here:

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.workout_listview);
listview.setAdapter(new WorkoutListViewAdapter(this, new String[] {...}));

listview.setClickable(true);
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,  int position, long id) {
        System.out.print("CLICK");
    }
});

listview.setLongClickable(true);
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        System.out.println("LONG CLICK");
        return true;
    }
});
```

This code causes nothing to happen when a list item is clicked and displays "LONG CLICK" when one is long clicked.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774408/onlongclick-stopping-onclick) question, which seems to have the same problem but the code is structured very differently, and my code is already following the answer's guidelines of implementing the listener on the ListView rather than the row.

Comment: Because its void!!!

Comment: What if you remove OnItemLongClickListener? Then OnClickListener will work?

Comment: Because onItemClick is void and onItemLongClick returns a boolean. This is the way android is set up, it's not something I can change (or would want to) as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, if I remove anything relating to the long click listener then onClickListener works just fine

Comment: ListView has very known bugs. It's not recommended since RecyclerView introduced. Can you use RecyclerView instead?

Comment: Check this link, I think your answer might be there: http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/click-long-press-event-listeners-list-activity/

Comment: Switching their positions did not work, and my code is almost word-for-word identical to that demo. I cannot see any difference. I am currently looking into RecyclerView but if possible I would like to avoid restructuring all my code.

Comment: Please post the activity and the adapter code